# SQL Merge two Tables

Tags: sql

Let's say I have these 2 tables:

ArticleTBL

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|articleid| typeid   | price       | user       |  
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|   0     |    2     |  1          | 122        |
|   1     |    3     |  2          | 344        |
|   2     |    3     |  1          | 455        |
|   3     |    1     |  4          | 34         |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

TypeTBL

```
+---------+----------+-------------+
|typeid   | type     | factory     |  
+---------+----------+-------------+
|   0     |  wooden  |  factry1    |
|   1     |  plastic |  factry2    |
|   2     |  metal   |  factry3    |
|   3     |  sth.    |  factry4    |
+---------+----------+-------------+
```

How do I request all this information only with `articleid` for each row?

Comment: You're looking for a "join". Here's some info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/28719292

Comment: Please add the expected outcome.

Comment: No, your answer doesn't make sense to me because the condition "WHERE article_id=0" was not intended - or at least the author didn't mention this. Furthermore, which outcome is exactly intended, should be explained by the author and then people can replicate whether your answer and/or another one satisfies that.

Comment: a little, but like Jonas Metzler said, i think it only shows one row. I will check later if I can make it work with this solution.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Comments discussing a specific answer belong in the comments section of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want? [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/28719292)

```
SELECT     a.articleid,
           a.price.a.USER,
           t.typeid,
           t.type,
           t.factory
FROM       form ArticleTBL a
INNER JOIN typetbl t
ON         a.typeid = t.typeid
WHERE      a.articleid = 0
```

Comment: the query is correct but you do not need to apply where clause. In this manner all record will be shown.